# Django + jinja2. Where to place new template tags?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I've read documentations and more SO questions and do not understand where to place template tags's code and how to load it. I'm very confused with it.

So i have standart django's project with standart file's tree. In django, we created new tags in `app_label/templatetags/template.py` and load them from template by `{% load template %}` tag.

In jinja2 I do not understand how to reproduce this without any 3rd party apps. Even when i'm using `{% load %}` template it raises exception

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /users/
Encountered unknown tag 'load'.
```

### NOTE

I've read about [extensions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#module-jinja2.ext) but don't know where to place it and how to load within template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jinja2 you do not load the tags from the template page.

["Extensions are added to the Jinja2 environment at creation time. Once the environment is created additional extensions cannot be added."](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#adding-extensions)